# Nested loop to pull JSON database elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, ejs

I am attempting to create a dynamic group within a select2 field while I pull my data from a JSON file. I'm using a nested loop to first loop through the states, then loop through the colleges in that state. The `<optgroup>` label should be the state and the `<option>` should be the college.

What you see below is my current code, representing what I've tried.

**JSON file with database info:**

```
var collegeData = [
    {
    'Ohio': 
        [
            {name: 'Colllege of Wooster', value: 'cow'}, 
            {name: 'Ohio State University', value: 'osu'}
        ],
    'Arizona': [
            {name: 'Arizona State University', value: 'asu'}
        ]
    }
];
```

**Select2 with ejs loops:**

```
<select class="single-select" id="college" name="college">
  <option value="default"></option>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < college.length; i++) {%>
      <optgroup label="<%=college[i] %>">
        <% for(var j = 0; j < college[i][j].length; j++) {%>
         <option value="<%=college[i][j].value %>"> 
         <%=college[i][j].name %></option>
      <%}%>
    </optgroup>
  <%}%>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/collegeApp';

app.get('/', function(rep, res){
    mongodb.connect(url, (error, database) => {
        const db = database.db('collegesApp');

        if (error) return process.exit(1);
        console.log('Connection is linked');

        const collection = db.collection('colleges');
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('index', {  nav, college: results });
        });
    });
});
```

**Ideal output in HTML:**

```
<select class="single-select" id="college" name="college">
  <option value="default"></option>
      <optgroup label="Ohio">
         <option value="cow"> College of Wooster</option>
         <option value="osu"> Ohio State University</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Arizona">
         <option value="asu"> Arizona State University</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

The error I receive is a `Cannot read 'length' of undefined`, so I know there is something wrong. My thought is that it is something to do with my syntax, but if you have other thoughts I would be happy to hear.

I've also already taken a look at W3Schools JSON Arrays article, as well as a codeburst article on JSON arrays. Neither was as specific as I needed.

Thank you!

Comment: how do you send `collegeData` in your ejs file? post your controller

Comment: What is the output of `results`? You reading data from mongodb, not from JSON file.

Comment: `collegeData` is used for my  `/addeventsdata` route where I insert the JSON elements to the database. The controller provided queries that collection and returns with the result when my index is rendered, hence the `college: results`.

Comment: ok, `console.log(results)` after `if (err) throw err;` and post here the output

Comment: @dimitristseggenes `console.log` output: `[
  {
    _id: 5cf1e2efa50290d19e70d329,
    Ohio: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    Arizona: [ [Object] ]
  }
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
1. Execute this query in your controller to exclude `_id` from the result.

```
collection.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function(err, results){
...
```

2.Try the following loop in your ejs file.

```
<select class="single-select" id="college" name="college">
  <option value="default"></option>
  <% college.forEach((coll) => { %>
    <% Object.entries(coll).forEach(([key, value]) => { %>
      <optgroup label="<%= key %>" >
        <% Object.entries(value).forEach(([cKey, cValue]) => { %>
           <option value="<%= cValue.value %>"> <%= cValue.name %> </option>
        <% }); %>
      </optgroup>
    <% }); %>
  <% }); %>  
</select>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I gave this a try and it works for the most part, although now I have an `_id` option and two blank options in the `<options>` fields. How can I remove these? It displays: `_id`, ``, ``, `Ohio`, `College...`, `College...` etc.

Comment: did you change your query as i mentioned?

Comment: Yes, `collection.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function(err, results)...`

Comment: is the `console.log(results)` still the same?

Comment: Identical as before, yes.

Comment: try this `collection.find({},{projection:{_id:0}}).toArray(function(err, results)`

Comment: That did it! Thank you! If you don't mind can you explain the `projection:` you added? I am unsure of what it does. Thanks again.

Comment: projection is used to select which fields you want to return from a query. you can read more here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field

Comment: Thank you I’ll check it out!